# Find all values of $\text{Log}(e^z)=z$

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms, exponential-function

Find all possible values of $\text{Log}(e^z)=z$.
 I'm thinking the way to go about this is: 
 $$\text{Log}(z)=\ln|z|+i\,\text{Arg}(z)$$ 
 So $$\text{Log}(e^z)=\ln|e^z|+i\,\text{Arg}(e^z)$$ 
 $$\text{Log}(e^z)=z+i\,\text{Arg}(e^z)$$ 
 But how do I find $\text{Arg}(e^z)$?

Comment: Please clarify what you want to know. What does it mean to find a value of an equation? Do you want to find solutions of the equation?

Answer (score 2):

Note that $e^z=e^xe^{iy}$.

The argument of $e^z$ is, therefore, multivalued with $\arg(e^z)=y+2n\pi$.

Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
\log(e^z)&=\log(|e^z|)+i(\arg(e^z))\\\\
&=x+iy+i2n \pi\\\\
&=z+i2n\pi
\end{align}$$

If $n=0$, then $\log(e^z)=z$.

For all other branches of $\log(e^z)$, $\log(e^z)\ne z$.